# PowerShell Script to restart the Application Pools of WFEs

Tags: 2013, powershell, iis, application-pool

Need to create a `PowerShell` script to recycle the `Application Pool` of my `WFE` - Dev,Staging & Production servers of my `SP 2013 Farm`.

I tried code mentioned
 [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/rwillgoss/archive/2012/11/25/how-do-i-recycle-an-iis-app-pool-with-powershell.aspx)

But somehow as mentioned in the blog, it seems, its applicable to `Win Server 2008` only.
Also I tried  [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/0448a533-b0ac-4ece-9f2a-7c5924df1c8b/how-to-recyle-a-particular-application-pool-in-iis-using-powershell-script-all-i-have-is-a-site?forum=winserverpowershell) 
too:

```
  # Load IIS module:
 Import-Module WebAdministration
 # Set a name of the site we want to recycle the pool for:
 $site = "Default Web Site"
 # Get pool name by the site name:
 $pool = (Get-Item "IIS:\Sites\$site"| Select-Object     
 applicationPool).applicationPool
 # Recycle the application pool:
 Restart-WebAppPool $pool
```

Don't know what I am missing here

Answer (score 5):

```
# Load IIS module:
Import-Module WebAdministration
# Adds registered Microsoft SharePoint PowerShell snap-ins
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
# Get SharePoint Web Application
$app = Get-SPWebApplication http://site/
# Get pool name from web application:
$poolName = $app.ApplicationPool.Name
# Recycle the application pool:
Restart-WebAppPool $poolName
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the following PowerShell code:

test is the name of the Application Pool

```
import-module webadministration
$a =  get-item IIS:\AppPools\test 
$a.recycle()
```

Comment: Restart and Recycle are not the same thing.